# Is it possible to send data from device (e.g. MPU6050) to Arduino through cut/hacked USB cable?

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, mpu6050

So I understand the USB cable consists of VCC, GND and Data+, Data-.

[image]

Is it possible to connect an MPU-6050 gyro to these 4 pins, especially data+/-, and still receive them normally through the SCL/SDA pins on the Arduino?

The goal is to make an input piece modular by having an USB out at it while having an USB in at the Arduino.

Here is a basic visualization:

[image]

Comment: No, the i2c bus is not meant to go through a cable.

Comment: Just make sure you keep the VCC and GND wires the same as USB, so that in the event someone plugs it into a PC, thinks don't get damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execellent non-Arduino question about I2C cable so the answer is also non-Arduino. I recommend the following Hackaday blog. https://hackaday.com/2017/02/08/taking-the-leap-off-board-an-introduction-to-i2c-over-long-wires/. You can find a more theoretical model in https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/I2C-Cabling.pdf

Basically yes you can use cables. Different cables have different level of capacitance per meter. This will reduce the maximum frequency and may also require adjustment of the pull-up resistors.

Cheers!

BW: "nihil novi sub sole": This question has been asked before, https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=143337.0

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just did it with simply connecting the wires and was suprised that it worked, but it's actually just a long wire in the end, right? So of course it should work. But now I'm wondering what if I needed one more pin (e.g. the AD0 of the MPU)? Can I somehow manually put one more wire inside the USB?

Comment: Why all the trouble? There are a lot of different cables out there. USB has four wires so that is a limit. How about using an Ethernet cable? Or even Telephone cable. In any case do not forget to accept the answer if it was just that.

Comment: You're right, gonna do something similar!